# Cannot send mail in Jenkins when Running it from war file

Tags: email, ssl, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, tls1.2

I am using Jenkins version 2.7.1 in Windows Server 2008.
I am running Jenkins in java environment with java -jar jenkins.war command.

I am trying to send mail with smtp.office365.com -- where I am getting an error "com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: xxx.x.x.xx SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM"

I read that we need to Enable TLS in jenkins.xml

But I couldn't find where Jenkins.xml file will present ??
If we install the msi file and run Jenkins as a windows service we can get the Jenkins.xml file in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins

But as I am just running my war file - I have no Jenkins folder in Program Files

Could anyone please help me to enable tls for jenkins.war

Answer (score 1):

If you have deployed your Jenkins on Tocat you can set the TLS flag in setenv.bat file in tomcat conf folder.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - Yes, that would work if I run my jenkins from Tomcat server.
But in my case I would like to have that separate.
So I am running from cmd alone.
The below command helped me to set the flag If started from cmd with java war.

java -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true -jar jenkins.war